# Processing My sprite wont move

Tags: java, processing

could you help me to make my sprite walk left and right ? i just cant see where the problem is.
I've spend 3 hours looking at the code but i just cant see where i've made mistake ...

```
class Player {

  PImage playerr;
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  float direction;
  float speed;
  float ground = 600;
  float left;
  float right;

  Player()
  {
    playerr = loadImage("sir1.png");
    position = new PVector(400, ground);
    direction = 1;
    speed = 4;
    velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
  }



void update()
{
    velocity.x = speed * (left + right);
    PVector nextPosition = new PVector(position.x, position.y);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(position.x, position.y);
    scale(direction, 1);
    image(playerr, 0, 0);
    popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == RIGHT)
  {
    right += 5;
    direction = -1;
  }
  if (key == LEFT)
  {
    left -= 5;
    direction = 1;
  }
}

void keyReleased()
{
  if (key == RIGHT)
  {
    right = 0;
  }
  if (key == LEFT)
  {
    left = 0;
  }
 }

}
```

and that's the main program

```
int stage;
PFont startfont;
PFont normalfont;
PImage gameplan;

boolean[] keys = new boolean[526];

ArrayList knight;

void setup()
{
  size(800,800);
  frameRate(60);
  stage = 1;
  knight = new ArrayList();
  smooth();
}

void draw()
{
  switch(stage)
  {
    case 1:
      splash();
      break;
    case 2:
     game();
      break;
    case 3:
      help();
      break;
    case 4:
      help();
      break;
   }

}

void game()
{
  gameplan = loadImage("background.png");
  gameplan.resize(800,800);
  background(gameplan);
  knight.add(new Player());
  for(int i = 0; i <knight.size(); i++)
  {
     Player p = (Player) knight.get(i); 
     p.update();

  }


}

void splash()
{
    background(0);
    startfont = createFont("start.ttf",40);
    normalfont = createFont("start.ttf",25);
    textFont(startfont);
    text("Zombie Destruction",100,300);
    textFont(normalfont);
    text("Press Space to start",200,400);
    text("Press H for help",250,500);
    if(keyPressed)
    {
      if(key == 'h' || key == 'H')
      {
        stage = 4;
      }
    }
    if(keyPressed)
    {
      if(key == ' ')
      {
        stage = 2;
      }
    }
}
void help()
{
    background(0);
    startfont = createFont("start.ttf",40);
    normalfont = createFont("start.ttf",25);
    textFont(normalfont);
    text("Zombie Destruction",100,300);
    textFont(normalfont);
    text("Press Space to go back",200,400);
    if(keyPressed)
    {
      if(key == 'b')
      {
        stage = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        stage = 4;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is preferable that you do not input your whole executing code, but rather a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Please consider updating your code to help others to help you.

Comment: You should also tell *what* the problem is, ie. what the program actually does versus what you want it to do.

Comment: @hyde im sorry for the gramar mistakes. my brain doesnt work anymore. Basically it is a simple game with a splash screen. I want the player to move. i've placed the sprite into array list and the used the game() function to output the sprite. The problem is that the sprite is printed but it doesn't move. Im guessing there is something wrong with the player class but im not sure what.

Comment: Well, first thing to do is narrow the problem down by adding debug prints or setting breakpoints and examining variable values with debugger. Does the code get keypresses? Are relevant variables updated with keypresses? What actual numeric results do your calculations produce? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in the Player class's update() method. It looks like you're calculating the updated velocity, but you never add that velocity to the player's position. A simple

```
position.x += velocity.x;
```

should do the trick.